# Set a String value from a Image in an ImageView Button

Tags: android, imageview

I have an `ImageView Button` which loads 3 different images ("tick", "cross" and "N/A"-as an image) every time it's clicked on. What I want to do is when the user presses a button:

1. If "tick" is selected save it as `String "true"` in the local database.
2. If "cross" is selected save it as a `String "false"` in the local database.
3. If "N/A" is selected save it as a `String "null"` in the local database.

Code where images change after every click:

```
private void configureImageButton1() {
    imgBtnOne = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtn1);

imgBtnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        //increase counter to move the next image.
        currentImage++;
        currentImage = currentImage % numImages;

        //Set the image depending on the counter.
        switch(currentImage)
        {
        case 0: imgBtnOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick);
        break;

        case 1: imgBtnOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.redcross);
        break;

        case 2: imgBtnOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_applicable);
        break;

        default:  imgBtnOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.tick);
        }
    }

});
```

I have seen everywhere however unable to find exactly what I need. Any pointer or guidance will be much appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the string value in the switch statement. for example:

```
...
case 1:
    imgBtnOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.redcross);
    currentValue = "false";
    break;
case 2:
...
```

For the database access... take a look at this tutorial:
http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike. I'll experiment it as i have got 25 `imagebuttons` and let you know. If possible can I have your email, in case you're not here by then, still I can tell you via email.

Comment: You can just post a comment to my reply and I will get notified.